# Python issue using try statement pump turning on automatically

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

Hello currently having an issue while executing a script. The pump attached to the mycobot is turning on when running the script immediately when I want it to wait to turn on. To attempt to fix this issue I tried an if statement the issue still occurs.

```
from pymycobot.mycobot import MyCobot
from pymycobot import PI_PORT, PI_BAUD
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

mc = MyCobot(PI_PORT, PI_BAUD)

#Used to for pump on and off functions
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(7,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(1,gpio.OUT)

def pump_on():
    gpio.output(7,0)
    gpio.output(1,0)
        
def pump_off():
    gpio.output(7,1)
    gpio.output(1,1)

#Home position for cobot
def home_pos():
    mc.send_angles([-86.39, 27.24, -114.08, 148.44, 89.64, 152.57], 15) #Checked
    
def lego_drop():
    mc.send_angles([-169.62, -23.02, -54.66, -9.93, 4.04, 162.68], 15) 

def lab_pick_up():
    mc.send_angles([-38.93, -66.44, -17.4, 5.0, 7.91, 162.68], 15) #Checked
    
def pick_up_avoidance():
    mc.send_angles([-39.55, -62.13, -29.26, 15.46, 10.54, 155.65], 15) #Checked
  
def vgr_avoid():
    mc.send_angles([1.49, 11.42, -110.65, 135.26, 5.62, 155.65], 15)
    
angles = mc.get_angles

try:
    home_pos()
    time.sleep(3)
    mc.send_angles([-38.93, -66.44, -17.4, 5.0, 7.91, 162.68], 15)
    time.sleep(3)
    if angles ==[-38.93, -66.44, -17.4, 5.0, 7.91, 162.68]:
        print("cobot is ready for pick up")
        pump_on()
        mc.send_angles([-169.62, -23.02, -54.66, -9.93, 4.04, 162.68], 15)
    else:
        pump_off()
    if angles == ([-169.62, -23.02, -54.66, -9.93, 4.04, 162.68], 15):
        print("cobot is at drop off")
        pump_off()
    else:
        pump_on()
    mc.send_angles([-86.39, 27.24, -114.08, 148.44, 89.64, 152.57], 15)
    print("Cobot phone home")
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    gpio.cleanup()
    home_pos()
    exit
```

Comment: `angles` is not defined anywhere, so presumably it will be of value `None` and therefore the `if` statement never activated.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure but you probably forgot `()` in `angles = mc.get_angles()`. You could also check what you have in `angles` - `print(angles)` - because it can be something different then you expect in `angles == ([...values...], 15)`

Comment: you forgot `()` in `exit()`